# coderush templates for MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, coderush

Am in the process of creating my own set of coderush templates for MVC both on the HTML side and in the code-behind.
Am wondering if anyone has gone through the same process and has put them anywhere on the public domain where I could obtain them rather than "reinventing the wheel"?

Otherwise will put together a list of the templates myself and post them on the public domain somewhere.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 10.2 update of CodeRush includes a number of new MVC templates as well as new declaration and navigation features for MVC. I suggest contacting support@devexpress.com to get what you need (e.g., a daily build or perhaps a final version of 10.2, depending upon when you contact support).

Comment: Ahh thanks for that Mark. Will get in touch with them and see what they say. Is this release going to be made available any time soon?

Comment: Have contacted support about the templates and hopefully can see if the build is forthcoming. Thanks again!

Comment: CodeRush 10.2 will ship sometime this quarter, but probably not as soon as you would like. All DevExpress .NET products ship simultaneously, so we can't put a final CodeRush 10.2 in your hands until all our .NET products are ready to go.

Comment: Thanks for the information Mark. Managed to get access to 10.2 and so can hopefully get access to the templates. THanks for taking the time to respond!

Comment: 10.2 would be an awesome christmas present. :)

Comment: Dennis, my expectation is that you'll certainly get 10.2 before Christmas.

Comment: Here's the list of CodeRush code templates for  ASP.NET MVC development for C# and VB: http://bit.ly/iSstcD